# How to add environment variables. Vagrant and WSL

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm using Vagrant within WSL.

As per the Vagrant website on WSL I'm supposed to add a environment variable to allow Vagrant to access certain Windows programs etc.

`export VAGRANT_WSL_ENABLE_WINDOWS_ACCESS="1"`

I have no idea where I should be adding this. Does this go in my Vagrantfile ?
If so, can you please provide me with an example of basic implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you still want to run with WSL, this should do the trick

you need to run this in your shell prompt (not add to your Vagrantfile)

```
$ export VAGRANT_WSL_ENABLE_WINDOWS_ACCESS="1"
```

Add this part to your Vagrantfile

```
config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
  vb.customize [ "modifyvm", :id, "--uartmode1", "disconnected" ]
end
```

This was reported in [vagrant issues](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/8604)

Answer (score 3):

Add Vagrant access to Windows permanently so you do not need to enable it every time you launch bash:

```
echo 'export VAGRANT_WSL_ENABLE_WINDOWS_ACCESS="1"' >>~/.bashrc
```

This will add VAGRANT_WSL_ENABLE_WINDOWS_ACCESS="1" to you .bashrc

Relaunch Ubuntu, done

Answer (score 1):

After reading some articles. I realized that perhaps using Vagrant from within WSL was a bad idea, as it's "not fully optimized yet". I opted to rather go the alias route and use the copy of Vagrant on my Windows 10 environment.